# Can not execute gcc in Mac OS Lion

Tags: macos, gcc, osx-lion

howto install gcc when, using Xcode the message comes "package not trusted" ? 
I installed with brew install gcc, and it installed gcc, but I am unable to use it:

```
brew install gcc
Warning: gcc-4.9.2_1 already installed
$ gcc-4.9.2 -o hello.o hello.c
-bash: gcc-4.9.2: command not found

$ gcc-4.9.2_1 -o hello.o hello.c
-bash: gcc-4.9.2_1: command not found
bidu:~ bidu$ whereis gcc
bidu:~ bidu$ whereis make
```

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the command line tools.

```
>>> xcode-select --install
```

See http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/

Comment: Am I missing something? This gives me an output with help options, but not a popup asking to install the command line tools. I'm working with lion

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found this:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#
Then I installed the command-line tools for my mac version as a dmg.

This worked.